# How to use if statement in awk, for a file which has date and other values in delimited format in linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a linux file with the below format, my requirement is the date (value) which are coming in the file in the columns (5,7) should be cut as per my substr command.

Moreover, the 5th and 7th columns are those columns which may or may not contain the date(values.), so I need a if statement to correct the date values if present.

Kindly correct me with the proper script.

**SAMPLE FILE:**

```
*# cat zx
7b540eda6b89136432213fbe09815c12,50281271950,,,20160524 08:14:26+0400,,20160524 08:14:26+0400,,7b540eda6b89136432213fbe09815c12,,,
7b540eda6b89136432213fbe09815c12,50281271950,,,,,20160524 08:14:26+0400,,7b540eda6b89136432213fbe09815c12,,,
```

**My Script:**

```
awk -F "," '{print $1,$2,"",'BEGIN{if($5==""){print substr($5,1,4)"-"substr($5,5,2)"-"substr($5,7,11)}}',$6,'BEGIN{if($7==""){print substr($7,1,4)"-"substr($7,5,2)"-"substr($7,7,11)}}',$8,$9,$10,$11,$12}' OFS=, zx
```

**ERROR THROWN:**

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: I have doubts about using `BEGIN` inside that statement, since it is meant to be used only at the beginning, before processing the file...

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","} length($5)>0{$5=substr($5,1,4)"-"substr($5,5,2)"-"substr($5,7,11)} length($7)>0{$7=substr($7,1,4)"-"substr($7,5,2)"-"substr($7,7,11)} 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
7b540eda6b89136432213fbe09815c12,50281271950,,,2016-05-24 08:14:26,,2016-05-24 08:14:26,,7b540eda6b89136432213fbe09815c12,,,
7b540eda6b89136432213fbe09815c12,50281271950,,,,,2016-05-24 08:14:26,,7b540eda6b89136432213fbe09815c12,,,
```

Comment: @ Chet : i know to take that but i need all values and i need to do substr on the values of 7th and 5th column if values are there . so only i used  awk to grep all the values in my output.

Comment: can you add an example output for the data value expected after substr?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my Solaris machine:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F',' '{printf "%s,%s,%s,", $1,$2,""} length($5)>0{printf "%s,", $5=substr($5,1,4)"-"substr($5,5,2)"-"substr($5,7,11)} {printf "%s,", $6} length($7)>0{printf "%s,", $7=substr($7,1,4)"-"substr($7,5,2)"-"substr($7,7,11)} {printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $8,$9,$10,$11,$12}' zx
```

Output:

```
7b540eda6b89136432213fbe09815c12,50281271950,,2016-05-24 08:14:26,,2016-05-24 08:14:26,,7b540eda6b89136432213fbe09815c12,,,
7b540eda6b89136432213fbe09815c12,50281271950,,,2016-05-24 08:14:26,,7b540eda6b89136432213fbe09815c12,,,
```

Comment: data missing from your o/p after 7th column